# Kendo Datepicker Onchange event not working

Tags: input, onchange, onfocus, arrow-keys, kendo-datepicker

kendo-datepicker I have used change event but it's not shwoing edited date on calendar. Editing date focus should be go on calendar. closed calendar & open again then it's show edited date. Change event does not fire

[text](https://dojo.telerik.com/aWaZusek/7)